# Show errors on login page even if login is attempted on a different page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a login form on my welcome page that POSTs to the login route

If there are errors, I want them to show on the login page, not go back to the welcome page. The problem is that if there are errors, it is going back to the welcome page.

I looked through the code and it looks like `back()` is responsible for this, so I narrowed it down to the session `previousUrl`. I've tried using `session()->setPreviousUrl(route('login'))` in my welcome page controller, but did not resolve the issue.

How do I make it so it will show the errors on the login page even if the user is attempting to login from the welcome page?

**Edit:** This is a Laravel app which is using the built-in auth scaffolding for the login.

Comment: This is a Laravel app which is using the built-in auth scaffolding for the login.

Comment: You try to use   `redirect('route')->withInput()`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to @atymic for his help but I figured it out this way (which is very similar):

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw (new ValidationException($validator))->redirectTo(route('login'));
    }
}

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ])->redirectTo(route('login'));
}
```

Need to throw an exception on `validateLogin` as just returning a redirect does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by overriding the `validateLogin` and `sendFailedLoginResponse` functions on the controller.

```php
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

```php
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw new ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ])->redirectTo(route('login'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks I used a similar solution since returning the redirect in `validateLogin` does not work correctly in your example.